# How to get activity title name through programmatically java android

Tags: java, android

In my android application, I set title name of an activity in `AndroidManifest.xaml` like below:

```
<activity
       android:name=".LoginSuccess"
       android:label="Home" > // this is title name
</activity>
```

And activity title name is `Home` and I wan to get this actitvity title name in my actitvity's java page, I am trying like below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_sample);

        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        pageTitle = actionBar.getTitle().toString(); 
}
```

But I am getting below exception at this line `pageTitle = actionBar.getTitle().toString();` :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Kindly suggest me, what can I do to resolve this issue,

waiting for reply.

Thanks.

Comment: Mb it's beacuse you trying to get title before it creates. Try to get title with delay.

Comment: post the stack track

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can also get like this from `PackageManager`

```
ActivityInfo activityInfo = getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(
                getComponentName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
String title = activityInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager())
                .toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
String classTitle = actionBar.getTitle().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you trying to get title before it creates.

You can try do it with delay in your `onCreate` method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_sample);

         new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() { 

                 android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                 pageTitle = actionBar.getTitle().toString(); 
            }
        }, 500);
}
```

It works fine.

Comment: I put same above code, but its not getting title. and its not going into the `run()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Define your strings in the Strings.xml and then try to do the same thing with delay it may work.

Answer (score 0):

I know it´s been a while since the last post but for those (like me) searching a solution for this issue.... you don´t need action bar to get the Manifest´s activities label, just do the follow in your Activity´s onStart:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    String pageTitle = getTitle();// it´s not available in onCreate yet
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code to get current activity name in your class file.

```
this.getClass().getSimpleName()
```

Comment: This will give you the class name NOT the label .